# How to determine EUR (or USD) price from Poloniex Ticker?

Tags: api, ticker

**Poloniex** has for me a strange ticker content.

Rest API URL: https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker

I have no problem with other plateforms to determine an immediate price, for example EUR / BTC price.

But with Poloniex, there is no EUR_BTC pair... only crypto to crypto pairs.

Example (actual BTC price = 1170€):

```
BTC_ETH 
id  148
last    "0.07956500"
lowestAsk   "0.07977149"
highestBid  "0.07956501"
percentChange   "-0.00406771"
baseVolume  "2206.78596466"
quoteVolume "28048.32458745"
isFrozen    "0"
high24hr    "0.08127295"
low24hr "0.07676536"
```

With tickers, a *volume* is usally a Dollar amount... here, I don't know.

How to calculate a Euro or Dollar price with such info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTC_ETH is the exchange information between Bitcoin and Ethereum. In your example, 1 Ether buys about 8% of a Bitcoin.

The volume is given in both BTC and ETH terms.
baseVolume says 2206 BTC have been traded against ETH (last 24h I think)
quoteVolume says 28000 ETH have been traded against BTC

If you want a price in USD you can check the BTC_TUSD ticker, as the Tether-USD price is similar to the real USD price.

Comment: Can't it be real USD instead of a crypto? Why such plateforms don't give change rate for state currencies? I'm more seaching BTC_EUR in fact...

Comment: Polo simply doesn't offer trading in traditional fiat currencies. Just like you can't buy or sell gold on there, you can't buy or sell EUR.